# Making a function for type casting generics more abstract and reusable

Tags: kotlin, generics

I working in on a service that heavily uses generics and I have a function in several of my classes that looks like this to handle type casting safely:

```
    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    inline fun <reified R : Info> cast(): EmailEvent<R> {
        return try {
            (this as EmailEvent<R>).also { emailEvent ->
                R::class.validateCast(emailEvent.info::class)
            }
        } catch (e: ClassCastException) {
            throw WrongEventTypeException(
                message = "Wrong EmailEvent type",
                expectedType = R::class.java.name,
                actualType = info.javaClass.name,
            )
        }
    }
```

The validateCast function looks like this:

```
fun Collection<KCallable<*>>.findByNameAndReturnType(name: String, returnType: KType): KCallable<*>? {
    return this.find { kCallable ->
        kCallable.name == name && kCallable.returnType == returnType
    }
}

fun KClass<*>.validateCast(castCandidate: KClass<*>) {
    castCandidate.members.forEach { member ->
        this.members.findByNameAndReturnType(member.name, member.returnType)
            ?: throw ClassCastException(
                "${this::class.simpleName} could not be cast: " +
                    "${member.name} is not present in ${castCandidate.simpleName}"
            )
    }
}
```

It seems silly to have to provide this function to several different classes when the logic is the same. What I want to do is either create and abstract class that these classes can inherit or a standalone function that can be used by all of these classes. In general, the classes look something like this:

```
data class EmailEvent<T: Info> (
    val someId: String,
    val type: SomeEnumType,
    var someNum: Int,
    val info: T
)
```

I've tried created an abstract class that takes in type parameters to make this inheritable, however, it seems that type parameters can not have type parameters (i.e. `T<R>` is not allowed a return type `fun <T, R> something()`) . I also tried to create a standalone function that takes in both values, but that doesn't seem to work either. I feel like I'm just missing something.

Any suggestions?

Comment: At a glance, it doesn't seem like you're missing anything.